# JavaFX - onCloseRequest() overrules my boolean statement

Tags: java, javafx, window

In my GUI for my program, I have a line:

```
window.setOnCloseRequest(closeProgram());
```

This is run whenever the user presses the `X` button on the Window frame (not a button I made, but is default on every single GUI application).

`showWarningWindow` is a boolean method which shows a confirmation window about closing the program. If true, it will run `Platform.exit();`

I am 100% sure that my `showWarningWindow()` method returns `false`, and yet the application still closes. Why is this and how can I stop it from happening?

```
/**
 * This method is called when the user wishes to close the program.
 */
private void closeProgram()
{
    if (logic.unsavedChangesExist())
    {
        if (showWarningWindow("You currently have unsaved changes made to the database."
                + "\nAre you sure you would like to exit without saving?"))
        {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty),

> The installed event handler can prevent window closing by consuming the received event.

So you need

```
window.setOnCloseRequest(event -> closeProgram(event));
```

and

```
private void closeProgram(WindowEvent event)
{
    if (logic.unsavedChangesExist())
    {
        if (showWarningWindow("You currently have unsaved changes made to the database."
                + "\nAre you sure you would like to exit without saving?"))
        {
            Platform.exit();
        } else {
            event.consume();
        }
    }
}
```

Without this, your window will close no matter the return value of `showWarningWindow`. If it happens to be the last window open, and `Platform.isImplicitExit()` returns true (the default), then [the application will exit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit-boolean-).

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly and makes sense. Thanks a lot!